# How to left-join the first previous/next instance of a has_many reference based on a parameter

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

Running Rails 7 on Ruby 3.2 with PostgreSQL 15.1.

First, I'd like to give an abstract example:

Cats:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ricewind |
| 2 | Tiffany |

Toys:

| ID | cat_id | greatness |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

**The problem I want to solve is:**

Based on an not-saved-yet toy and its greatness, I want to get a list of all cats and their toys which are just below or greater than the one I want to create.

If given a new toy with `greatness=4`, the result should be:

| cat_id | toy_prev.greatness | toy_next.greatness |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | *NULL* |

**Requirements:**

- Both toys should be "left-joined" as they do not need to be existing.
- Only one row per cat
- I would need full access to the models, including the cat and both toys, not only the `greatness` attribute.

The pseudo-code I like to use later would be sth like:

```
Cats.with_toys_by(4).each do |cat|
  [cat.id, cat.toy_prev.greatness, cat.toy_next.greatness]
end
```

**Things, I've tried so far:**

1. The most simple solution would be to just iterate over `Cat.all` and within this loop, call `@cat.toys.where("greatness < ?", 4).order(greatness: :desc).first()` to get the left side and `@cat.toys.where("greatness > ?", 4).order(greatness: :asc).first()` to get the right side. this is very unperformant as this triggers N+2 queries.
2. Using `has_one` with a `where()` condition did not work as this cannot be used directly in the main query's `joins`.

**Things, I'm thinking about:**

If I would write it in plain SQL, I would left-join the `Toy` table two times in both directions:

```sql
SELECT cats.*, t1.* FROM cats
  -- makes sure the requirement matches
  LEFT JOIN toys t1 ON (cats.id = t1.cat_id AND t1.greatness < 4)
  -- filter out ones which would have toys with a greater greatness, a.k.a. get the first one
  LEFT JOIN toys t2 ON (cats.id = t1.cat_id AND t1.greatness < t2.greatness)
  -- same for the other side
  LEFT JOIN toys t3 ON (cats.id = t3.cat_id AND t3.greatness > 4)
  LEFT JOIN toys t4 ON (cats.id = t4.cat_id AND t3.greatness > t4.greatness)
WHERE
  t2.id IS NULL AND t4.id IS NULL
```

`t1` would be `toy_prev`, the one with the lower greatness - and `t3` would be `toy_next`.

Dispite using `Arel` would be an option, I did not used it yet and I don't really like the idea for the following reasons:

- `Arel` is a private API and is discouraged to be used publicly.
- It seems to give a hard time when trying to map between the hashes returned and the model-instances. Further filtering or using `Arel` and the ORM at the same time, like `Cats.where(..).with_toys_by(4).limit(5)`, seems not to be supported, at least if `Arel` is not only used for a `where`-clause.

Is there a "clean" solution to my problem using the offical ORM directly?
Or do I need to fall back to `Arel`?

Comment: You can use the raw sql -- just create it in a SQL view -- then make an active record  model based on the SQL view.  Then you get to query it like any other model.